# React Native Prop Not Being Passed To Child Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using **react-native-router-flux** as a router. This is my very first RN app in which I have a Home screen, and a chat screen. My home screen is working fine, and I am able to successfully navigate to to the chat screen upon button press. However, my home screen has an enough form and the value that the use enters (name) I want to pass to the chat screen as a prop.

Main App component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Chat from './components/Chat';

import {
  Router,
  Stack,
  Scene,
} from 'react-native-router-flux';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Stack key='root'>
          <Scene key='home' component={Home} title='Home' />
          <Scene key='chat' component={Chat} title='Chat' />
        </Stack>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Home component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Actions,
} from 'react-native-router-flux';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.title}>
          Enter your name:
        </Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.nameInput}
          placeholder='why so serious??'
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.setState({name:  text})
          }}
          value={this.state.name}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            Actions.chat({
              name: this.state.name,
            })
          }}
          >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            Next
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 20,
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  nameInput: {
    padding: 5,
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'black',
    margin: 20,
  },
  buttonText: {
    marginLeft: 20,
    fontSize: 20
  }
})

export default Home;
```

if I alert this.state.value on the onPress() function, the value is being captured and alerted.

However,

```
Actions.chat({
              name: this.state.name,
            })
          }}
```

isn't recieving this input value. When the app goes to the chat screen it just says "hello"

Chat component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

class Chat extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          Hello {this.props.name}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Chat;
```

Am I simply over looking something here? any help is appreciated in passing prop from home to chat component.

edit: 
In the chat component when i alert(this.props.name) it alert Hello chat. The key from `<Scene key='chat' component={Chat} title='Chat' />` in the app component is being passed down instead of the input value from the home component. Not sure why this is happening

Comment: Reading the code it seems to be ok. Can you try adding `constructor(props) { super(props); }` to your Chat component? Let me know if it helps

Comment: @soutot That didn't change anything. I used alert(this.props.name) and the alert shows 'chat.' The key from <Scene key='chat' component={Chat} title='Chat' /> is being passed down as prop for some reason.

Comment: Thats odd. Can you please make the following test? Pass one more prop like this `myTest: 'helloworld'`, then in your Chat component add a `console.log(this.props)`. Let me know the result of console.log. Hope it can clarify us a little more.

Comment: For sure, I went ahead and did this. Here's the result https://imgur.com/a/S7OWX

Comment: it's odd how the value for name is set to chat here

Comment: lol, i changed the key from name to myName and it worked! I guess it was a naming issue. Thanks for your help soutot. The console.log with myTest made me try changing the key name which ended up fixing the issue.

Comment: It looks like `name` prop is reserved by RNRF to identify the `key` value. I couldn't find anything related to it in the docs. I think you can use another prop name for awhile. I will keep looking for an official answer to this, or maybe someone else can give an answer with more details

Comment: Great. I'm glad to help

Answer (score 0):

seems like name is reserved prop for action key you can do something like that

```
Actions.chat({
   userName: this.state.name,
  })
```

and in your chat class

```
class Chat extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <View>
       <Text>
        Hello {this.props.userName}
       </Text>
    </View>
  )
 }
}
```